# Can one be allowed to use a house for free because he is able to use that house for free?

Tags: talmud-gemara, real-estate, bava-kamma

As per [Bava Kama 20a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=21&daf=20&format=pdf), a squatter who does not benefit from a property, where the owner does not lose anything from the squatting, need not pay rent. Rashi explains [there](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.20a.18?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) that the squatter is not considered to benefit from the use of this property because "שכיחי ליה בתים בחנם" -- he has houses available for him to use, free of charge. I assume that this particular case is an instance where the squatter's access to the other houses is legal; [an earlier comment by Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.20a.17?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) refers specifically to borrowing and owning those other houses.

What if the squatter does not have *legal* access to any houses, but has access to two houses (that are not generally rented out) *as a squatter*? His free access to House A is predicated on his free access to House B, which in turn is based on his free access to House A. Is this man able to use either house for free? Is there a problem if the reasoning allowing him to use these properties is circular in nature?

Comment: I don't have the source, but I'm pretty sure that although zeh neheneh v'zeh lo chaseir patur it's still assur except in very specific cases of kofin al midas sedom.

Comment: (I'll admit that the title is not the greatest. If you have a better suggestion, I'd be glad to hear it as a comment.) ("You" is no one in particular.)

Comment: @DonielF Could be. I couldn't find the word "אסור" on https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%96%D7%94_%D7%A0%D7%94%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%95%D7%96%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%97%D7%A1%D7%A8, for whatever that's worth. This case, anyway, is a case of זה אינו נהנה וזה אינו חסר.

Comment: Why isn't he benefitting?

Comment: @DonielF Because he has other houses available to him for use, gratis. See the Rashi that I linked to in the question post.

Comment: I understand that. But according to that logic there's never a case of Zeh Neheneh v'zeh lo chaseir.

Comment: @DonielF Not true. What if he doesn't have any houses that he could use without paying? See the next few lines of gemara, after the parts that I refer to here.

Comment: Isn't that exactly your case? He's using both of these houses illegally.

Comment: "Free" and "legal" are two different values, @DonielF.

Comment: Mimah nafshach that should hold the answer to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57717/discussion-between-shokhet-and-donielf).

Comment: I always assumed he had houses available for free with owner's permission. Otherwise the argument is circular.

Answer (score 1):

**He shouldn't have to pay.**

You have to first understand what the gemara means in that the sqautter is not receiving benefit. Of course he's receiving benefit! He's living in a house! He's not out in the cold! Rather, the gemara means he's not gaining money; he's not the type of person who rents out houses. Rashi gives a logical explanation of why- he has other houses available to him for free. But the reason he doesn't have to pay isn't because he could've went to a different house, it's because he never would've paid for *this* house. So therefore, as long as he's the type of person who would not pay to rent a house whether on not he is able to squat elsewhere, he wouldn't have to pay.

Comment: (I know it's a shoilah of Ov)